# Variable is undefined, despite being defined inside an if-statement

Tags: matlab, octave

I was writing a program to add a Gaussian noise with zero mean and unit variance
to a signal without using the in-built function in octave:

```
t=0:0.001:2;
x1=sin(2*pi*10*t); 
x2=sin(2*pi*5*t)+sin(2*pi*50*t);
x3=x1+x2;
d=0;
L=length(x3);
for i = 1:L
d+=(abs(x3(i))^2);
endfor

Es=(1/L)*d;
SNR=20;

for i = 1:L
if (real(x3))
noise=sqrt(Es/SNR)*randn(1,L);
elseif (imag(x3))
noise=sqrt(Es/(2*SNR))*(randn(1,L)+(i*randn(1,L)));
endif  
endfor
x4=x3+noise;

fs=1000;
N=1024;

y=fftshift(fft(x4,N));

fval=(fs/N)*(-N/2:N/2-1);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,x4,'g');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('x4(t)');

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(fval,y,'b');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('X4(f):Frequency Response');

figure
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(fval,abs(y),'r');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Amplitude Response');

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(fval,angle(y),'m');
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Phase Response');
```

But I am unable to sort out an error that keeps showing up:

```
    error: 'noise' undefined near line 27 column 7
```

How can I get around this error?

Comment: If you have an error message which refers to a line number, always mark the line in your posted code or mention which line it corresponds to in your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect the logical value of `real(x3)` to be? That's what you're asking. It's like asking *If apple, do ...* What is *apple*? Since that is not a binary value, and neither is `imag(x3)`, your `if` statement will simply never execute. It's not clear what you want this `if` statement to do, but a few logical operations can be made as follows:

```
real(x3) > imag(x3)
real(x3) == imag(x3) % You might want to do this within tolerance
```

etc

As [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811887/andy) mentioned you might very well be looking for whether `x3` is real or complex, thus modify your `if` statement like so:

```
if isreal(x3)
    noise=sqrt(Es/SNR)*randn(1,L);
else
    noise=sqrt(Es/(2*SNR))*(randn(1,L)+(i*randn(1,L)));
endif
```

The difference is that if e.g. `x3 = 4`, `real(x3) = 4`, which is not a logical, whilst `isreal(x3) = true`.

There are a lot more issues with the code, like overwriting the `noise` variable every loop iteration with a full new array, mistaking your loop index `i` for the complex variable `i` etc, so I suggest you look at a proper basic tutolrial for MATLAB/Octave programming as well.